# How do I encode this in answer set programming?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I am a total newbie to answer set programming, and I am struggling with a rather simple question. The program needs to be written in clingo.

So here is the question:

> An abstract argumentation framework consists of a set A of arguments
> and an attack relation R ⊆ A X A between them. For any two arguments
> a1 and a2, if (a1, a2) ∈ R then we say that a1 attacks a2: if one
> admits argument a1 then it casts doubts on argument a2. Formally, a
> subset of arguments E ⊆ A is stable if the following two conditions
> hold:
>
> 1. no arguments in E attack any other argument of E.
> 2. any argument outside of E is attacked by an argument from E.
>
> Write an ASP program that identifies stable subsets of arguments in a
> given instance through answer sets. The instance will be provided via
> two predicates argument/1 and attack/2 corresponding to A and R
> respectively.

Here is an example:

```
argument (a).    
argument (b).    
argument (c).    
argument (d).    
attack (a,b).    
attack (b,c).    
attack (d,c).
```

Valid output:

```
choose (a) choose (d)
```

This what I tried, which is obviously wrong:

```
choose(X)  :- argument(X), attack(X,Y).
```

I don't know how to approach this at all.

Please help.

Comment: I'm still interested in the lecture. Where do I find the slides and tutorials? We could be tutorial buddies ;P

Comment: @Raubsauger

Oh, sure I can share them with you once I complete my semester by second week of December. Right now it is only available on my university portal, but we are allowed to download them at the end of the semester.
Would you mind taking a look at this one? Pretty sure it will be a piece of cake for you!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64765161/how-do-i-extract-the-trees-from-a-graph-using-answer-set-programming

Comment: This would be nice. My ASP seminar was way too short :) Could you add your other question again? I'd like to see the whole question to answer it. Don't forget to show your attempt.

Comment: @Raubsauger
Done, I have modified the question description to include the entire task. And this time I have included my attempt as well, and also the line where I believe the problem is (I could be wrong). It is the same link I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm a beginner in ASP too, so this will take some time.

Comment: @Raubsauger Thanks a million, and please take your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple 3 Step solving approach is the following:

1. describe the facts (check)
2. generate what you want as a result, but leave the program a choice
3. give rules which solutions do not apply

So start with 2:

generate possible outcomes. Think of it in simple words: *For every argument I choose it or not.*
The *may or may not* part can be solved with a subsum `{}`.

```
{choose(X)} :- argument(X).
```

or even simpler: *I choose a subsum from the arguments*

```
{choose(X):argument(X)}.
```

Lets check the solutions with [Potassco](https://potassco.org/clingo/run/) and `#show choose/1.`, resoning mode `enumerate all`:

```
Answer: 1

Answer: 2
choose(b)
Answer: 3
choose(c).
..
Answer: 15
choose(a) choose(b) choose(c)
Answer: 16
choose(a) choose(b) choose(c) choose(d)
SATISFIABLE
```

All combinations are found. Time to remove the wrong stuff. Again: think of it in simple words: *It is not possible that I choose two arguments where one attacks the other.* (If the head is left open, this is read a False.)

```
:- choose(X), attack(X,Y), choose(Y).
```

Now check it again:

```
Answer: 1

Answer: 2
choose(a)
Answer: 3
choose(d)
Answer: 4
choose(a) choose(d)
Answer: 5
choose(c)
Answer: 6
choose(a) choose(c)
Answer: 7
choose(b)
Answer: 8
choose(b) choose(d)
SATISFIABLE
```

Now we need to make sure every not choosen argument is attacked by a at least one choosen element:

```
1 {choose(Y):attack(Y,X)} :- argument(X), not choose(X).
```

Reads: *For every argument `X`, which is not choosen,* the number of choosen arguments which attack it, is at least one.

Lets check it:

```
Answer: 1
choose(a) choose(d)
SATISFIABLE
```

Nice.

Since the contraints are normally formulated with an empty head, lets reformulate the last rule:

```
:- argument(X), not choose(X), {choose(Y):attack(Y,X)} 0.
```

Reads: *There is no argument `X`, which is not choosen and has maximum 0 choosen arguments, which attack `X`.* It gives the same output.

Complete code:

```
argument (a;b;c;d).   
attack (a,b).    
attack (b,c).    
attack (d,c).

{choose(X):argument(X)}.
:- choose(X), attack(X,Y), choose(Y).
:- argument(X), not choose(X), {choose(Y):attack(Y,X)} 0.

#show choose/1.
```

Comment: Wow, you are a genius! Thank you!