# How do I extract the trees from a graph using Answer Set Programming?

Tags: undirected-graph, answer-set-programming, clingo

> There is an undirected graph (V,E), weights on the edges w : E → N, a
> target k ∈ N, and a threshold O ∈ N. Find a k-vertices tree of the
> graph of weight less than the threshold. In other words, select k
> vertices and k - 1 edges from V and E respectively such that they
> constitute a tree, and the sum of the weights of the selected edges
> are less than O.
>
> Write an ASP program that takes V , E, w, k, and O as input, and finds
> a selection of edges satisfying the constraints, or outputs
> ‘unsatisfiable’ if the constraints cannot be satisfied. Selecting the
> edges implicitly induces a selection of the vertices, so there is no
> need for the selected vertices to be explicitly displayed.
>
> An instance to this problem is provided through predicates vertex/1,
> weight/3, target/1, and threshold/1. All edges have weights, so
> statements of the form weight(a, b, 10). can be used to declare the
> existence of an edge between vertices a and b at the same time as
> declaring their weight, and there is no need for any redundant edge/2
> predicate.

I tried the following:

```
% instance
vertex ( v1 ). vertex ( v2 ). vertex ( v3 ). 
vertex ( v4 ). vertex ( v5 ). vertex ( v6 ). 
vertex ( v7 ). vertex ( v8 ). vertex ( v9 ).
weight ( v1 , v2 ,3). weight ( v1 , v3 ,3). 
weight ( v2 , v4 ,1). weight ( v2 , v5 ,5). 
weight ( v3 , v4 ,3). weight ( v3 , v6 ,4). 
weight ( v4 , v5 ,4). weight ( v4 , v7 ,1). 
weight ( v5 , v7 ,7). 
weight ( v6 , v7 ,2). weight ( v6 , v8 ,2). 
weight ( v7 , v9 ,3). 
weight ( v8 , v9 ,2).
target (4).
threshold (4).

% encoding
(P-1) {select(X, Y) : weight(X, Y, Z)} (Q-1) :- target(P), target(Q).
sum(S) :- S = #sum {W,X,Y : select(X,Y), weight(X,Y,W); W,X,Z : select(X,Z), weight(X,Z,W) }.
:- sum(S),threshold(M), S > M.
:- select(A,B), select(C,D), A == C ; A == D ; B == C ; B == D. 

#show select/2.
```

And I get the following output:

```
clingo version 5.5.0
Reading from stdin
Solving...
Answer: 1
select(v2,v4) select(v4,v7) select(v6,v7)
Answer: 2
select(v2,v4) select(v4,v7) select(v6,v8)
Answer: 3
select(v2,v4) select(v4,v7) select(v8,v9)
SATISFIABLE

Models       : 3
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.013s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.000s
```

I was expecting just

```
select(v2,v4) select(v4,v7) select(v6,v7)
```

because the others clearly are not tress.

I think this is because of the problematic line:

```
:- select(A,B), select(C,D), A == C ; A == D ; B == C ; B == D.
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: Ok, a first attempt is to limit the number of selected nodes to target which will give the right output for the example. But it does not force a tree.

Comment: You are right, although it will not work (I think) if the target was changed to 5 and everything else stays the same? Because the target is based on the weight, and isn't related to the number of nodes. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that was rather complicated. I'm pretty sure my solution is not perfect, I'm a beginner too.

Before we start with the code, let's check up the question once more: The requirement is to select `k` nodes and `k-1` edges. If you think about it a bit this can form exactly two patterns: one connected tree or multiple non-connected graphs where there is at least one cycle. So if you make sure not to have a cycle you get one connected tree.

I added some nodes to the facts to check if a tree was formed or if the cheap unconnected cycle was found, and for doing so I had to change `target` and `threshold` to higher values.

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlaSV.png)

```
#const n = 5.

vertex ( v1; v2; v3; v4; v5; v6; v7; v8; v9 ).
vertex ( m1; m2; m3 ). 
weight ( v1 , v2 ,3). weight ( v1 , v3 ,3). 
weight ( v2 , v4 ,1). weight ( v2 , v5 ,5). 
weight ( v3 , v4 ,3). weight ( v3 , v6 ,4). 
weight ( v4 , v5 ,4). weight ( v4 , v7 ,1). 
weight ( v5 , v7 ,7). 
weight ( v6 , v7 ,2). weight ( v6 , v8 ,2). 
weight ( v7 , v9 ,3). 
weight ( v8 , v9 ,2).
weight ( m1 , m2 ,0).
weight ( m2 , m3 ,0).
weight ( m3 , m1 ,0).
target (n).
threshold (6).
```

And now comes the code, followed by an explanation.

```
% select subset of nodes and vertices
(P) {select(X) : vertex(X)} (P) :- target(P).
(P-1) {select(X, Y) : weight(X, Y, Z)} (Q-1) :- target(P), target(Q).
     
% postion does not matter in an undirected graph.
directed(A,B):-select(A,B).
directed(B,A):-select(A,B).

% for every selected edge all nodes are selected
:- directed(A,_), vertex(A), not select(A).

% for every selected node there exists at least one edge
:- select(A), {directed(A,B):vertex(B)}0.

% select a direction for each selected edge
{dir(A,B);dir(B,A)}==1 :- select(A,B). 

% force them in an order
{ found(X,1..n) } == 1 :- select(X).
{ found(X,N):select(X) } == 1 :- N = 1..n.
% reject if one edge does not follow the order 
:- found(X,NX), found(Y,NY),  dir(X,Y), NY<NX.
% reject if 2 different edges end in the same vertex 
:- dir(X,Z), dir(Y,Z), X!=Y.

:- threshold(M), M < #sum {W,X,Y : select(X,Y), weight(X,Y,W); W,X,Z : select(X,Z), weight(X,Z,W) }.

#show select/2.
```

Explanation:

- To make it easier for me I added the selected vertices in the `select/1` predicate.
- Since dealing with undirected graphs always has to check both postions I added the `directed/2` predicate which is a directed graph version of the selected edges.
- Next I made sure every selected vertex has a selected edge and vice versa.
- Now comes the complicated part: to detect cycles. For this I forced every selected edge in one of its two directions by using the predicate `dir/2`. Testing for a tree is easier in a directed graph.
- Next I put an order `found/2` to the vertices. The directed edges `dir/2` where only allowed to go with this order. This forces cycles to a certain behavior.
- Now comes the cycle destroyer: if the selected graph has a cycle then two edges from `dir/2` will end in the same vertex. REJECT. If this was just an unlucky guess from clingo then it will find a luckier guess which fullfills this criterion.
- Computation of the sum was copy and paste from you.

The output is 16 times

```
select(v2,v4) select(v4,v7) select(v6,v7) select(v6,v8)
```

The dublicates come from the fact that the order of the vertices in `found/2` can differ but still get the same result.

Comment: Wow thank you!

Just a question, where in the code are you assigning a value for n? I went through the code a few times, but couldn't find the assignment. 
Also, I double checked it on clingo, and it does complain about the value of n not being assigned.

Reading from stdin
-:36:11-15: info: interval undefined:
  1..n

-:37:38-42: info: interval undefined:
  1..n

Any suggestions?

Comment: oh sorry, I did alter the code in the post to make it shorter and forgot about it. I added the `#const n = 5.` on top of the facts. Note `target (n).` as well

Comment: Great, that works flawlessly!

A follow up question for my understanding. Instead of assigning a numeric value to n directly, is it possible to get this value from threshold? For example, if I mention the fact threshold(4)., is it possible to extract the value '4' from this predicate and assign it to a variable n? I tried n :- threshold(n)., but it is obviously wrong. I come from an object oriented programming background, so the syntax and flow of ASP programs are really confusing to me.

Comment: Thanks again! Just that these answers will be automarked by a  computer, and a human is unlikely to even see it. The facts will just be supplied to the program (which means, target4) will be a fact), and since setting a constant value and then using target(n) is not standard input (according to the problem statement), the test cases will eventually fail. Damn, I really hate automarking! Oh, and in my previous comment, I meant to say target(n) instead of threshold(n).

Comment: Done, thanks again! You are a guardian angel, and a genius too!